# express3 js req.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express2.js when using req.body I get undefined or empty {}:

```
exports.post = function (req: express3.Request, res: express3.Response) {
    console.log(req.body);    
});
```

I have the following configurations:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.post('/getuser', routes.getuserprofile.post);
```

The request body is in XML and I checked the request header which was correct.

Comment: Why do you have `: express3.Request` things in arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I missed the part where you had XML. I guess req.body doesn't parse by default.

If you are using Express 2.x then perhaps [this solution](https://gist.github.com/davidkrisch/2210498) by @DavidKrisch is adequate (copied below)

```
// This script requires Express 2.4.2
// It echoes the xml body in the request to the response
//
// Run this script like so:
// curl -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<hello>world</hello>' http://localhost:3000
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

express.bodyParser.parse['application/xml'] = function(data) {
    return data;
};

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});


app.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.contentType('application/xml');
    res.send(req.body, 200);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `express.bodyParser()` supports XML.  It only supports url-encoded parameters and JSON.

From: http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware

> **bodyParser()**
>
> Request body parsing middleware supporting JSON, urlencoded, and
>   multipart requests.