# node js req.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, post

First of all I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353395/node-js-req-body-undefined), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861148/express3-js-req-body-is-undefined) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153001/req-body-is-empty-express-js).

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.post('/user_create', (req,res) => {
    console.log("trying to create a user "+req.body);

    const firstName = req.body.first_name
    const lastName = req.body.last_name

    console.log("first name is "+firstName+" "+lastName);

    res.end()
})
```

Now after trying all the post given above, I am still getting req.body undefined, I am newbie in Nodejs. I am using express 4.16.4 and body-parser 1.18.3.

Comment: please try 'postman' to test your request manually.  how are you actually sending your data to the service.  depending on the way you send them you need another way... req.params / etc...

Comment: @jcuypers I am sending data through a html form

Comment: @jcuypers I used 'postman' and that's working but why it's not working using form

Comment: try with something like this.  {headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}))  when sending the request

Answer (score 0):

```
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
};
```